# В чем ошибка sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Есть телеграм бот, в который если прописать /start, то он добавит пользователя в базу данных sqlite3 если его там не было. При перезапуске бота, если открыть профиль то выдает ошибку на подобие что пользователя нету в базе данных, хотя он там есть! Если также после перезапуска сначала написать /start, то в базе данных ничего не добавляется, значит пользователь там есть, но после если написать профиль, та же самая ошибка

Текст ошибки:

```
File "C:\Users\tornado\Desktop\changer\changer.py", line 269, in cmds
    profile(message)
  File "C:\Users\tornado\Desktop\changer\changer.py", line 134, in profile
    user = list(cursor.fetchone())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Код:

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

# конект к дб юзеров
conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db", check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE users (id int, balance int, transactions int, turnover int, ltc_rate_min int, ltc_rate_max int)""")
except:
    pass
conn.close()

# токен
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
# если старт
def welcome(message):
    # подключение к дб
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db", check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?"
    tg_id = message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute(sql, [(tg_id)])
    # если пользователя нету в дб то добавляем
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        new_user = """INSERT INTO users VALUES ({0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)"""
        tg_id = message.from_user.id
        cursor.execute(new_user.format(tg_id))
        conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    # запуск alarm!
    t = Thread(target=alarm, args=(message, ))
    t.start()

    menu(message)

# отправка профиля
def profile(message):
    # отправка клавиатуры
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item0 = types.KeyboardButton(" Пополнение")
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(" Вывод")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton(" Меню")
    markup.row(item0, item1)
    markup.row(item2)

    # получение данных из дб
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db", check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?"
    tg_id = message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute(sql, [(tg_id)])

    # данные
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите /start")
    else:
        user = list(cursor.fetchone())
        id = user[0]
        balance = user[1]
        transactions = user[2]
        turnover = user[3]

        conn.close()

        # отправка сообщения
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Профиль\nИмя: {}\nID: ".format(message.from_user.first_name) + str(id) + "\nБаланс: " + str(balance) + " р.\nСделок совершено: " + str(transactions) + " шт.\nОборот: " + str(turnover) + " р.", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Очевидно, вы уже прочитали пользователя в первом fetchone, и во втором fethchone считывать уже нечего (пользователь-то один, а не два), а значит результат второго fetchone всегда обязательно будет None

Comment: @andreymal когда открывается профиль, бот заново подключается к базе и заново получает fetchone

Comment: У вас в профиле целых два fetchone — первый возвращает пользователя, второй всегда возвращает None, потому что пользователь всего один

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в этом куске кода:

```
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:        # возвращает пользователя
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите /start")
    else:
        user = list(cursor.fetchone())   # а здесь уже возвращает None, 
                                         # т.к. пользователь был прочитан тремя строками выше
```

Перепишите его на что-то наподобие этого:

```
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите /start")
    else:
        user = list(data)
```